# How to restore a LUKS partition?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, gpt, luks

My /home partition disappeared on my main HDD. I changed SATA slots, then I got strange "no lvm available" errors during boot when usually the password would be entered (I do not have any lvm setup at all btw) ...

My BIOS retested itself and set up the SATA Ports to legacy IDE mode, maybe this caused this mess. Anyway I eventually was about to boot but 2 partitions have been disappeared now.

I had this.

```
sda1 - tiny GPT something partiton (never really understood if this is needed or not but I have seen OSes create this) - disappeared
sda2 - /boot
sda3 - swap
sda4 - /     LUKS->btrfs
sda5 - /home LUKS->btrfs - disappeared
```

I really wished it would be the root partition not me /home looks like every 2nd partition is gone.

I like to restore my home partition now. Good thing is I have the LUKS header. The bad is that I do not have the space to clone this drive so I can not make any mistakes now thats why I ask here.

[I read on the Arch Wiki how to restore with a header.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Restore_using_cryptsetup)

```
cryptsetup -v --header /mnt/<backup>/<file>.img open /dev/<device> test
```

I did this but I am not sure if this expects me to put the partition where device is /dev/sda5 or just /dev/dev/sda because because I did this with /dev/sda the command was actually a success but now I can not mount the mapped device. It said something with read only and that the Filesystem was not detected, then I should define it. That did not work euther (there should be no need since it should be detected right)

```
root@ubuntu:~# cryptsetup -v --header ~/Desktop/huge open /dev/sda check 
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda: 
No key available with this passphrase.
Enter passphrase for /dev/sda: 
Key slot 0 unlocked.
Command successful.
root@ubuntu:~# mkdir /oldhome
root@ubuntu:~# mount /dev/mapper/check /oldhome/
mount: block device /dev/mapper/check is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
root@ubuntu:~# mount /dev/mapper/check /oldhome
mount: block device /dev/mapper/check is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
root@ubuntu:~# umount /oldhome
umount: /oldhome: not mounted
root@ubuntu:~# man mount
root@ubuntu:~# mount -t btrfs /dev/mapper/check /oldhome
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/check,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

So maybe thats only for passing the actual partition but that is gone so what should I do now?

I have also read about Testdisk, since the other partitions are there maybe I have to somehow recreate the partition table?
Going to read this tomorrow: [Repairing GPT Disks](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html)

I would be glad for a answer from someone with experience.

**Update:**

I used gdisk now and it give me a "Warning! Secondary Partition table overlaps the last partition by 434 blocks. You will need to delete the partition or resize is in another utility.

gdisk not lets me try to resore backup GPT or write anything I tryed to disk because of this error.

Problem now is gnome-disks wont let me delete it "Cant have partition outside the disk" (its just the boot partiton I not care what happeds to it) and gparted detects the entire disk as no allocated space no partition show to delete unlike gnome-disks.

**Uptate 2**

The Windows 8 Disk manager let me delete the 2nd (boot) partition. It stil says the 2nd parition is overlapping but now the 2nd partition is what was the 3rd (my 40gb system partition). Should I delete all partitions that a can now and try that then my /home shows up?

I am curious should I not be able to read data from any point of the parittion with the header? David Foerster was trying to help me find the beginning of the LUKS partition with some dd | grep command but no luck.

**Update 3**

Deleted all partition under windows. Gnome disks shows still the sda4+5 my 40Gig sys partition is still there and accessable.

testdisk reports:

```
4000 GB / 3726 GiB
HOST PROTECTED AREA (HPA) present
```

what is this?

```
Continue even if there are hidden data
```

Maybe there are the missing parts? Hidden? Can I unhide them?

I also have the UUID of the partition from crypttab. Who can I search my entire disk for it?

Can I manually edit he GPT partition table and just edit system partition out?

**Update 5**

testdisk output so far - that "quick analysis" or whatever its called takes years.

```
TestDisk 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 4000 GB / 3726 GiB - CHS 486401 255 63
Analyse cylinder 58001/486400: 11%


  MS Data                     4096     491519     487424
  MS Data                  4397056    4401151       4096
  MS Data                 82522112   82526207       4096
  Unknown                192150642 20267801100156017 20267800908005376 [4$ ^P] 
  Unknown                340102217 1330174078621457 1330173738519240
check_FAT: Bad number of sectors per cluster
check_FAT: Bad jump in FAT partition
check_FAT: Bad number of sectors per cluster
  Unknown                828912837 22984364628 22155451792 [~F^?eM-@O]
```

I do not had/have a FAT partition. Ext2-swap-LUKS-LUKS

**Update**

I gave up, reformatted the drive

Comment: I had and read about people with similar problems after changing the access mode of SATA devices in the BIOS. Apparently the disk geometry changes that way, which is crucial to maintain for dm-crypt/LUKS and even partition tables. I suggest you reset that option to the previous setting “SATA” especially since legacy IDE mode is deprecated anyway and all modern desktop operating systems have full SATA support. This is a reversible, non-destructive operation, so you don't need to worry about backups unless you alter the disk content.

Comment: Well its back to its AHCI/SATA setting as it was always and I think this screwed up my partitions. Not sure if you are confusing the SATA/LEGACY IDE mode with AHCI here but I set both to the modern values I had before. Meaning Native mode for SATA Slots 1+2 and AHCI enabled. Demage is done, no going back this way I guess.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with MBR partitions only supporting 4 primary partitions or something but gdisk detecs that disk as GPT and its also 4TB so I cant try to go to MBR.

Comment: Yes, I meant AHCI or whatever you had set before the “retesting” of the BIOS (some BIOS know other modes like “RAID”). Are the diagnostics in your question done in the previous mode?

Comment: You shouldn't change anything on the disk like the partition table. Between MBR and GPT choose whatever provides the more plausible results, if you need to. While technically possible, I find it unlikely that an OS would offer to partition a 4 TB drive with MBR (which only supports partitions up to 2 TiB) over GPT.

Comment: No need to repeat me I know that. And yes all diagnostics where made in the BIOS settings I always had. The reset screwed it up by thinking its a RAID or a MBR or whatever. The thing is that gdisk shows the GPT table intact and not as "damaged" as in all the other examples I found on the net.

Comment: Ok, good. The state of the BIOS setting during your diagnostics isn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: I just saw that LUKS uses the character sequence `LUKS` as a magic sequence at the start of its headers. You could look for that on the raw device to find the right offset, if you cannot restore the original partition table. Following that within 256 bytes should be the names of the cipher and key derivation functions as well as the device UUID (which you may be able to recover from `/etc/crypttab`).

Comment: Good and how do I look for the sequence on the raw device? Should cryptsetup not do that for me on the event of trying to mount a partition with the backup header? Still curious if the command actually expects the device or the specific partition. I guess device but that did not work as described.

Comment: Oh wow, I totally overlooked the bogus `cryptsetup open` command. You need to specify the partition that holds the LUKS container, not the disk with the partition (e. g. `cryptsetup open --type luks [options] /dev/sda5` check). “Device“ is a bit ambiguous here since both are block devices from Linux' point of view.

Comment: From what I read `cryptsetup --header` doesn't look for the right offset. To search for the magic sequence you can use `grep -boe 'LUKS.\{,256\}'[UUID]` (if you can salvage the UUID). To only search a known range, pipe the output of `dd` with the appropriate range arguments to `grep`. Do you know how to do the calculations from the offset and size of the salvaged sda4? If not, we should go to a chat room.

Comment: No I don't, I can tell you "Last Sector: 82522111 (at 37.3 GiB) is the end of the sda4 according to gdisk and that sounds right. Can you now say me the command now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18007/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-redanimalwar).

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I could manage to at least find and read my files (untouched).

I write here what I did:

1. Do not panic (more than this!) and drink a glass of water.
2. Whatever you do, do not [WRITE] on your disk.
3. Get out of gparted, kde-partition manager and ..., **DISCARDING ALL THE CHANGES YOU WERE GOING TO DO.**
4. Open gparted or kde-partition manager again, ONLY FOR READING THE CURRENT TABLE. Do not make any change on the table using these applications.
5. Write down "starting sectors" and "ending sectors" of each part of the disk on a paper or a text file in your way. Try to be accurate.
6. If you have not changed the situation after the partition is gone, the starting of LUKS header is somewhere at (or near) the beginning of one of these parts.
7. Remember: The addresses you got from step 4 and 5 are "LBA" and not "CHS". We will use testdisk and it utilizes the latter.
8. Start testdisk **"Be sure to create a log file and do not skip it, if the log file exists append to it to avoid overwriting"**. Now make a scan (search for this in the internet). Right after the scan is done and saving a backup, copy .log files in your home directory (where testdisk saves) to a safe place.
9. Now use your start and end addresses from step 5 and create the missing partition (The partition type is the one you've used for your luks. Mine was LINUX for ext4.).
10. Recheck everything, save backup, keep the backup and log files and then write the table. LUKS header will be determined by the system, but you might not be able to open the disk like before.
11. Perform "sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/[THE NEW DEV] luksrecover"
    where [THE NEW DEV] is the address of just added partition. It creates a "luksrecover" partition in /dev folder heading to your added partition (and unlocked).
12. After step 11, the drive is unlocked. If the window manager can not open it, don't panic. Go to testdisk again, chose that partition (not your disk) and "None" partition table. Now use the "LIST" command. You can see and copy your files. Hooray.

And again: ***"Consider you have to convert LBA addresses to CHS."***

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Generally, we prefer that any clarification requests happen in the comments (instead of email) so they can be useful to others that may have the same issue later. Hence, I’ve edited out the email.